# Display of only current response in shiny app for storing arbitrary data

Tags: r, shiny

I am developing a shiny app which stores the arbitrary data. I have referred [This link](https://deanattali.com/blog/shiny-persistent-data-storage/) for the same. I can able to display all the responses including previous responses, but i want to display only the current response, not all response. My code snippet is as given below:

```
library(shiny)
outputDir <- "C:\\Users/dell/Desktop/"
saveData <- function(data) {
  data <- as.data.frame(t(data))
  if (exists("responsesiq")) {
    responsesiq <<- rbind(responsesiq, data)
  } else {
    responsesiq <<- data
  }
  fileName <- "test_irty.csv"

  write.csv(
    x = responsesiq, sep = ",",
    file = file.path(outputDir, fileName), 
    row.names = FALSE, quote = TRUE
  )

}
loadData <- function() {
  if (exists("responsesiq")) {
    responsesiq
  }
}


fields <- c("acc", "staff_name")


shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    titlePanel(" System"),
    DT::dataTableOutput("responsesiq", width = 300), tags$hr(),
    numericInput("acc", "Acc Number", ""),
    selectInput("staff_name", "Staff Name",
                c("Rajivaksh " = "RT",
                  "Arvind " = "AKS",
                  "Ashutosh " = "AS")),
    actionButton("submit", "Submit")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {


    formData <- reactive({
      data <- sapply(fields, function(x) input[[x]])
      data
    })


    observeEvent(input$submit, {
      saveData(formData())
    })

    # Show the previous responses
    # (update with current response when Submit is clicked)
    output$responsesiq <- DT::renderDataTable({
      input$submit
      loadData()
    })     
  }
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `reactiveValues` to hold the current entry, which will trigger when clicking submit

```
   shinyApp(
      ui = fluidPage(
        titlePanel(" System"),
        DT::dataTableOutput("responsesiq", width = 300), tags$hr(),
        numericInput("acc", "Acc Number", ""),
        selectInput("staff_name", "Staff Name",
                    c("Rajivaksh " = "RT",
                      "Arvind " = "AKS",
                      "Ashutosh " = "AS")),
        actionButton("submit", "Submit")
      ),
      server = function(input, output, session) {


        formData <- reactive({
          data <- sapply(fields, function(x) input[[x]])
          data
        })

        tmp <- reactiveValues(df=NULL)
        observeEvent(input$submit, {
          saveData(formData())
          tmp$df <- t(formData())
        })

        # Show the previous responses
        # (update with current response when Submit is clicked)
        output$responsesiq <- DT::renderDataTable({
          input$submit
          #loadData()
          data.frame(tmp$df)
        })     
      }
    )
```